# Hyperledger fabric v0.6 chaincode_example05 query failed (Timeout expired while executing transaction)

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have set up hyperledger fabric v0.6 with 1 CA and 1 peer using docker-compose.  I have successfully deployed `chaincode_example02` which is invoked and queried "*a*" and "*b*" without problem.

Now I want to test on "*chaincode calling chaincode*" using `chaincode_example05`.  I run the following command to deploy successfully:

```
peer chaincode deploy 
   -u jim 
   -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example05 
   -c '{"Args": ["init","sum","0"]}'`
```

I run the following command to "*invoke*" it successfully:

```
peer chaincode invoke  
  -u jim 
  -n 7929510b01d27dadec6b42751662182c98c85decb58256defb686adb77fbe9d9bcc1acea9890d2650e186f4c2190e50dcd2020cc36455a220087baaa384390db 
  -c '{"Args": ["invoke","github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/example/chaincode/chaincode_example02","sum"]}'`
```

Now, when I run the following query command:

```
peer chaincode query 
  -u jim 
  -n 7929510b01d27dadec6b42751662182c98c85decb58256defb686adb77fbe9d9bcc1acea9890d2650e186f4c2190e50dcd2020cc36455a220087baaa384390db 
  -c '{"Args":["query","github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/example/chaincode/chaincode_example02","sum"]}'`
```

I got the following error messages:

> Error: Error querying chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc =
>   Error:Failed to execute transaction or query(Timeout expired while
>   executing transaction)

How can I make it work?

Comment: did you figure out what the issue was?